# getaddrinfo fails although ping works fine

Tags: c, sockets, unix, getaddrinfo

I have following snippet of code, which is just trying to get address family of a server address. srv_addr is passed from other places to this piece of code.

```
    struct addrinfo dinfo, *dptr = NULL;
    int error;

    memset(&dinfo, 0, sizeof(dinfo));
    dinfo.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;

    error = getaddrinfo(srv_addr, NULL, &dinfo, &dptr);

    if (error) {
        printf("error in validating server address: %s",
                gai_strerror(error));
       return -1;
    }
```

srv_addr can be hostname(string) or IPv4 or IPv6 address.

code works fine, if srv_addr is numeric address.

In case if srv_addr is hostname, sometimes getaddrinfo() fails although ping  works fine at the same point of time.

Error:
error in validating server address: hostname nor servname provided, or not known.
error code: 8 (EAI_NONAME).

I am sure that hostname is valid, what can be the scenarios where getaddrinfo() may fail, even if hostname is valid and ping-able.

I know that getaddrinfo() returns list of addrinfo structures and hence there can be multiple address families to be returned. But I am interested only in failure case here.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some more info? print out ``srv_addr`` before calling ``getaddrinfo``? what exactly is your ``srv_addr``?

Comment: As I said, it is just a hostname of an ubuntu server.
which is ping-able from my machine where above program runs.

Comment: what i meant was that maybe ``srv_addr`` might differ from a hostname that you're pinging

Comment: aah. Nope. I am sure about that.